# How can I add an AppleScript menu to my menubar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, menu, applescript

How can I add such a menu to the menu bar in my Cocoa application?

[image: screenshot]

Various applications, for example Coda, have this. Is there an easy way to do this or must I implement this myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The ApplScript Editor has a preverence page where you can activate "show apple script menu in menu bar" (or something similar worded)

Comment: True, but that shows a menu on the right hand side of the menu bar (next to the clock). I want it in my application's menu bar, and only with scripts that apply to my application.